# UseState onclick nothing happen

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I make a button to control the menu but I click the button and then nothing happen.There aren't run out any error msg.

```
const [display, changeDisplay] = useState('none')
  const [Icon, setIcon] = useState(<HamburgerIcon />)
  function Close() {
    return (
      <Box as='button' onClick={() => changeDisplay('none')}><CloseIcon /></Box>
    )
  }
```

```
<Box
            as="button"
            aria-label="Open Menu"
            position="relative"
            onClick={() => { changeDisplay('flex'); setIcon(<Close />) }}
            display={{ base: 'inline-block', md: 'none' }}
            margin={2}
          >
            {Icon}
          </Box>
```

Comment: Where `changeDisplay` function code ?

Comment: @MayurVaghasiya const [display, changeDisplay] = useState('none')

Comment: Provide some more details of your code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the following code:

```
onClick={() => { changeDisplay('flex'); setIcon(<Close />) }}
```

with:

```
onClick={() => {changeDisplay('flex'); setIcon(Close())}}
```